# Whatsapp last seen is blank and shows only when online

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

it looks pretty confusing and weird that some contacts the last seen is always blank and it shows up "Online" only when the contact is Online.

They haven't blocked me anywhere not have I. How this could happen?

Regards
Shiva

Answer (score -2):

Because in their settings, they have disabled for others to see their last seen time.